# iOS - How to detect which button triggered a segue, and how to display its content based on the button

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton, segue

My problem is that I have a view with different buttons inside: all the buttons are connected to the same segue (this is for a particular reason, i know it would be easier to make different segues, but that's what i need right now).

How can I detect which button launched my new segue, and how can i change the data on the new segue bases on that decision? (for example, my new segue has in imageview, which should load a different image for every button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the method `-prepareForSegue:sender:`, in the sender parameter you has a reference to the control that launch the segue, for example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourIdentifier"]) {
        UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        // do what ever you need with the button and segue
    }
}
```